# bat file to run sqlplus and then execute command based on result?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

Can I have a BAT file run a SQLPlus command, and then based on the result, execute a CMD command, and then another SQLPlus command?

I think it would look something like this

CheckRowCount.SQL file

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dmsn.ds3r_1xrtt_voice_trigger
```

BAT file:

```
sqlplus %USER%/%PASSWORD%@ORACLE @CheckRowCount.SQL
if ROWCOUNT < 1 goto :EX
c:\Autobatch\Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ClientJobSender.exe http://SERVER/spotfireautomation/JobExecutor.asmx c:\AutoBatch\backup\Trigger_Test.xml
:EX
```

but I don't think this is exatcly right, ROWCOUNT doens't seem like it would work, also, how would I execute another SQLPlus command after the CMD.

I'm very new to BAT files and SQLPlus

Comment: I only know about batch, so I can't tell you much, but the second line should be more like `if %ROWCOUNT% LSS 1 goto EX` (on the condition that you manage to get the row count in a variable). In batch `<` has a special meaning, so you have to use `LSS`; also you should not put a colon after `goto`, just the label is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and learn Powershell or python.  I used to build crazy batch files to automate processes and they were painful.

Powershell is much, much better at building such conditional scripts, especially with the ability to create and monitor sub-threads.  Python is great also for this.

The great advantage these bring is you can access the database (and the return results within your script to process and react to the data.

The disadvantage(?) is that you will need to learn one of these languages, but I personally do not see these as disadvantages at all, as they are much better than batch files.

Otherwise, foxidrive's answer should work for you.

---

Powershell example (kind of long, but the code can be reused):

```
function CreateConnection 
{
    param([string]$databaseHost 
      ,[string]$Port
      ,[string]$SID
      ,[string]$UserID
      ,[string]$Password
     )      
    process
    {   
    $ConnectString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID={2})));User Id={3};Password={4};"`
    -f $databaseHost,$port,$SID,$UserID,$Password
    write-host $connectString
    sleep 10
    $connection = new-object system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection( $ConnectString)             
    return $connection
    }
}   

$DBMSHost="somehost.somedomain.com"
$DBMSPort=1521
$SID="somesid"
$UserName="user"
$Password="password"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Data.OracleClient') | out-null

try {
        $Connection = CreateConnection $DBMSHost $DBMSPort $SID $UserName $Password
     }
catch
    {
        write-host ("Could not access Oracle database {0}"  -f $_.Exception.ToString())
        exit
        }           

    $Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as rowcount FROM dmsn.ds3r_1xrtt_voice_trigger"      // Added name to column to make life easier

    $data_set = new-object system.data.dataset
$adapter = new-object system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter ($Query, $Connection)
    [void] $adapter.Fill($data_set)
    $table = new-object system.data.datatable
    $table = $data_set.Tables[0]    // We now have the actual resukts data

    foreach ($row in $table)
    {
        if ($row.rowcount <1 )
        {
            $Application = "C:\Autobatch\Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ClientJobSender.exe"
            $Arguments  = "http://SERVER/spotfireautomation/JobExecutor.asmx c:\AutoBatch\backup\Trigger_Test.xml"
            $CommandLine = "{0} {1}" -f $Application,$Arguments
            invoke-expression $CommandLine
        }   
    }
```

Comment: can you schedule powershell scripts? reason I was going the bat file route is cause I wanted to schedule it via windows task scheduler to run every hour.

Comment: ok...so after weeks of not understanding this answer and just finally putting an effort to learn the basics of powershell...this is the best solution i've seen

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sqlplus command returns a simple number then this may work:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sqlplus %USER%/%PASSWORD%@ORACLE @CheckRowCount.SQL') do set rowcount=%%a
echo.rowcount is set to "%ROWCOUNT%"
if %ROWCOUNT% GTR 0 (
c:\Autobatch\Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ClientJobSender.exe http://SERVER/spotfireautomation/JobExecutor.asmx c:\AutoBatch\backup\Trigger_Test.xml
)
pause
```

Comment: is the %ROWCOUNT% correct? or should it be %CheckRowCount.SQL%? How does it know what %ROWCOUNT% is?

Comment: ok...so I saved the above as a .bat and .cmd file, ran them, but I only see a blank CMD console and nothing seems to be happening. Whats weird is that I can type in the CMD console it opens.

Comment: if I take out the @echo line, the CMD windows shows this when I launch the script: C:\AutoBatch\backup\bat triggers\>for /F "delims=" %a in <'sqlplus /@OMP1 @CheckRowCount.SQL'> do set rowcount=%a

Comment: Sorry not to have replied earlier.  %rowcount% is set to the output of the SQLplus command, which you have shown is 0 or a positive integer.   When it is not zero the next line will be launched.  I have added some debugging to the code so you can try it and see if any error message appear.

Comment: @foxdrive had to step away from this a little bit. still trying to get it to work..I ran this........for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sqlplus user/pass@P1 @BLOCK.SQL') do set rowcount=%%a
echo.rowcount is set to "%ROWCOUNT%"
if %ROWCOUNT% GTR 0 (
ECHO YES
)
pause.......but got %%a was unexpected at this time error

Comment: Tell me if the code I provided to start with works, and the %rowcount% shows the numbers.  I can't tell in your reply if the code is all on one line - are you typing it at the command prompt?   First try the command `sqlplus user/pass@P1 @BLOCK.SQL` and see that it prints a number.